# Staircase or two way switch wiring doubts

Tags: wiring, electrical

This is wiring for house. Will the old model wiring work? My electrician told me it's not a problem if both ends are of positive side in light bulb or fan, I know it won't turn on. But will it cause harm to fan or bulb?
 [image: OLD MODEL AND NORMAL MODEL STAIRCASE WIRING]

Answer (score 5):

Your approach will work but is illegal in the Netherlands.

The reason is simple.

Normally your bulb (load) is on one side connected to neutral and the switches are handling the live line. In your approach one can no longer be sure that the bulb is not connected to a live wire when not burning. So forbidden.

Comment: Decapod - Illegal in almost all countries.  At least those that have a codified electrical code.  Switching neutrals is dangerous.

Comment: @RDrast. Agree.

Comment: @RDrast countries without electrical codes *still* have catch-all laws requiring professional-standard work and consequences for hurting someone.  In those countries you are expected to *figure out* an appropriate code to follow, e.g. US or EU.

Comment: Wiring wise, that is also super hard to wire.  You are carrying hot and neutral instead of messengers.  Realistically in the field this is fed off different circuits, which means circuit X is using circuit Y's neutral - very bad!